# Set of solutions to probability quantile equation

Tags: quantile, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable taking its values over some set $S$, with cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F$. Let $\epsilon\geq0$. We define the set $S^*(\epsilon)$ as follows:
$$S^*(\epsilon)\triangleq\{x \in S:F(x-\epsilon)+F(x+\epsilon)=1\}$$

**What can be said in general about the behavior of the set $S^*(\epsilon)$ as a function of $\epsilon$?**

For example, $S^*(0)$ is a singleton containing only the median. But what about the case $\epsilon>0$? Is the set also a singleton? Let us consider three possible assumptions:

1. *Assumption 1*: $X$ is a discrete random variable with support $\mathbb N$, e.g. Poisson distribution, Binomial distribution.
2. *Assumption 2*: $X$ is a continuous random variable with support $\mathbb R$, e.g. Normal distribution.
3. *Assumption 3*: $X$ is a continuous random variable with support $\mathbb R^-$ or $\mathbb R^+$, e.g. exponential distribution.

This is a follow-up question on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204035/minimisation-of-the-epsilon-insensitive-loss-function).

Comment: I think the answer depends heavily on the type of distributions you're considering, e.g. symmetric around some $x$, discrete vs. absolutely continuous, etc. Because the key is to solve $F(x-\epsilon)=1-F(x+\epsilon)$, which is the intersection of two non-decreasing right-continuous functions. As you correctly point out, the median is a solution for $\epsilon=0$, but the existence of additional ones depend on the slope of such functions, their continuity properties, and so on. Do you know anything else about $F$?

Comment: For instance, if $F$ is descrete, there exists $\epsilon^*$ such that for every $\epsilon<\epsilon^*$, the median is in the set of interest. If the distribution is symmetric around the mean and continuous, for every $\epsilon>0$, the mean is always in the set of interest, and so on.

Comment: @antonzm I have updated my question. Your statement about symmetric continuous distributions and the mean is interesting, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be absolutely continuous and symmetric around $x_0$, with density $f$. Then, for every $\delta$, $f(x_0-\delta)=f(x_0+\delta)$. Integrate both sides to get $$1-F(x_0-\epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^\epsilon f(x_0-\delta)d\delta=\int_{-\infty}^\epsilon f(x_0+\delta)d\delta=F(x_0+\epsilon)$$
 Thus, if the distribution is symmetric around $x_0$, for any $\epsilon\geq 0$, $x_0\in S^*(\epsilon)$.

Comment: I will think more about the cases you mention, because it will pretty much depend on how quick $1-F(x+\epsilon)$ declines in $\epsilon$, with respect to how quick $F(x-\epsilon)$ does, as well as the flat ranges for $F$ in the case of discrete distributions.